# Custom domain on linux server apache2 Django

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm trying to set custom domain on my Django project, but still I'm receiving message `err_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. Ip works just fine.

Apache2/project.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.uczsieit.pl
        ServerAlias uczsieit.pl
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       Alias /static /home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog/conf/static
        <Directory /home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog/conf/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog/conf/media
        <Directory /home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog/conf/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
                                                                                                                                
        <Directory /home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog/conf>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog/conf/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/adam/personal_blog_project/personal_blog python-home=/home/adam/$        WSGIProcessGroup django_app


</VirtualHost>
```

I added domain to Django Allowed hosts and set Reverse DNS and A/AAAA Records as well.

In error.log of apache lack of info about errors.

Comment: Is Apache running?

Comment: Yes, running and ready to go :)

Comment: Connection Timed Out usually means your webserver isn't responding. Maybe your server isn't exposed to the internet on port 80? This kind of thing is hard to debug without access to the environment.

Comment: This is weird, when i put IP server address http://172.105.68.92/ it works just fine, but domain www.uczsieit.pl not. It doesn't even show any errors, just timed out. Don't you think is something between VPS and domain provider?